# How to resolve max execution time error in Drupal commons?

Tags: 7

Getting this error on xampp using drupal commons distribution , by opening localhost/commons

```
PHP Max Execution Time  30
Your PHP execution time is too low, please set it greater than or equal to 120 seconds.
```

What to do?

Comment: Set it greater than or equal to 120 seconds? Sorry, but what part of the message you don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

go to `php.ini` and then find `max_execution_time` and set `120` or more what u are comfort with.